# Change link color-popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Is there a way to change the link color to gray without the code glitching like at my site.
(code glitches and says Quick Nav. )

[Click here to see page with glitch](http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/sfasfd)

I only want **that** link to be bold **not** the other.

Heres the current code.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="JavaScript:newPopup('<font color="gray">http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/navigation/quick.html</font>');">Quick Nav.</a>
```

Also just to let you know the page is supposed to be a 404 error, thats where the glitch is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly..Could you be more specific?

Comment: basially there is a popup thats supposed to come up when you click the link. I want to change its color, but whe i do that it glitches. heres a example of a page that works but doesnt have the color i want,   http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/chatting.html (click the "Quick Nav." blue letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using CSS, you'd want to just take that link for the popup, give it a class name, and style the class name with the CSS.

Add these lines of CSS

#### CSS:

```
a.popup-link {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then change the link for the popup to the following:

HTML:

```
<a class="popup-link" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/navigation/quick.html');">Quick Nav.</a>
```

Comment: I just tried yours (The cod3e is still up there) and it stayed blue... but the glitch didn't come up.... Strangely the text decoration did work though......

Comment: Sorry about that. I made a quick edit, added an `a` to `a.popup-link`. I updated my answer

Comment: @Luiz187 Thanks for accepting my answer. If you would also upvote my answer, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. For changing the link color to gray:

   **CSS**:

   ```
   a {
       color: #848484;
   }
   ```
2. The reason your code is "glitching" is because of this line:

   ```
   <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="JavaScript:newPopup('<font color="gray">http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/navigation/quick.html</font>');">Quick Nav.</a>
   ```

   You need to escape double quotes within double quotes to make it work:

   ```
   <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="JavaScript:newPopup('<font color=\"gray\">http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/navigation/quick.html</font>');">Quick Nav.</a>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is a little cleaner practice.

http://jsfiddle.net/wkYJ5/3/

--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Popup window code
    var newPopup = function () {

        if (this.style.color === 'green' || this.style.color==='') { this.style.color = 'red'; } else { this.style.color = 'green' };

        var popupWindow = window.open(
            this.url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');

        return false;
    };
    setTimeout(function () {

        var qnLk = document.getElementById('qnLk');
        qnLk.onclick = newPopup;
        qnLk.url = 'http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/navigation/quick.html';

    }, 100);
</script>
```

--

```
<a id="qnLk" style="text-decoration:none;color:green;" href="#">Quick Nav.</a>
```

Comment: I tried your code, it didnt work....it stayed blue then turned red after you clicked the link